# Obfs4 connections don't work anymore on local wifi hotspot!

Tags: connection

I am using the latest version of Tor, and I can't seem to connect to the obfs4 bridge that comes with the bundle anymore. Only obfs3 works but it is too slow! I tried grabbing alternate bridges from bridges.torproject.org and none of them would work. Reinstalling the program did not fix the problem, and neither did running as administrator. Please help, I live in the United States. The wifi hotspot I use blocks tor connections so I have to use bridges. Obfs4 used to work last month and now it doesn't. I am using Windows 10.[image]

Comment: Trying a meek transport may be worth a try.

Comment: @P. Gerber thanks for reaching me, but the meek transports don't work.

Comment: It makes no sense that obfs4 doesn't work but obfs3 does, unless they're actively recognising obfs3 and allowing it. Could the censorship be based on both a blacklist and ports?

Comment: Same here. Used to work, but 7.0.a2 won’t connect via the default obfs4 bridges.
I too am connecting through a portal and it always worked here. It will connect after I uncheck the "does your ISP block or censor connections" box. Once it connects I can check the "my ISP blocks connections" box and it works fine. It’s only an issue when starting. I have a bunch of additional obfs4 bridges, but every time I use them it connects to the same UK server first. Might change if I rearrange their order since I don’t believe Tor currently randomizes them. As I added new ones I put them in numerical orde

Comment: Also could they have added some captive portal mechanism that you need to go through first?

Comment: I tried your method and it works, but it's even slower than obfs3. I am getting connected to the Greece bridges, when I should be connected to United States bridges.

Comment: @canonizing ironize yes there is a portal that needs you to login in order to use the wifi. I have always used obfs4 connections with Tor to bypass these portals. Now obfs4 doesn't work anymore and I'm stuck with obfs3 which is slow as dialup.

Comment: What makes you think you should be connecting only to US bridges? I don’t think that’s possible. And WHY would you want to connect to US bridges? IMO those are much more likely to be infiltrated and surveilled by US 3-letter spy agencies. If you aren’t concerned about being spied upon, then why are you using Tor at all? There’s really no reason to continue trying to make obfs4 work if privacy is not a priority of yours.

Comment: I use Tor to bypass the login portal of a wifi hotspot. The Greece bridges are always slow for me. The built-in United States bridge from obfs4 was always fast enough for me. If you are saying that it's not safe enough, then I'll start to use Canadian or Mexican bridges.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with US bridges, they are not more likely to be "infiltrated and surveilled".

Comment: `obfs4` is designed to bypass DPI, not captive portals.

Comment: i live in ireland am havin same problim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to download the new update that came out recently today and it fixed the problem for me. I am able to use obfs4 now. I appreciate those who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using other pluggable transports such as:

1. meek-amazon
2. meek-azure
3. fte
4. ...

If no one works then try to use IPv6 normal bridges (which you can get at bridges.torproject.org).

Comment: None of the transports work except for obfs3, which is as slow as dialup Internet. I checked the website and they don't have any IPv6 addresses on there. Obfs3 bridges from the site don't work for me either. I added a picture of the log file to see for yourself.